# Call duration during the call via AMI

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

How can I get call duration during the call via AMI?
something like Status() or CoreShowChannels() but seconds needs to be after Answering call

Answer (score 2):

You have following options:

1)You can collect "Link" events and store info about calls start in your application. AMI is not designed to got call info. This one is CORRECT way.

2) issue command
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Command
with
"core show channel CHANNEL_NAME_HERE"
It will have info about duration

3)Other option is get variable CDR(billsec)

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+GetVar